# Raspberry GPIO, time trigger

Tags: python-datetime, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to make a GPIO trigger by time.

The first part is just a test, the second part is a WHILE is to trigger the time, I used a IF statement to match the time I wanted. That worked very fine. But inside the While python gives me an error stating

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sleep'

I try to evoke:

```
from time import sleep
```

But still gives me error.

Here is the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime 
import time
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW) #Turns On
time.sleep(3)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH) #Turns off

print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))

while True :
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    print(time)
    if time == "06:16":
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(2)  # <===== This gives me error
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("YEah baby")
        break
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import time
from time import sleep

# ...

time.sleep(3)
```

Here, you're calling the `sleep` function from the `time` module, because when you wrote `import time`, you created a variable named `time` containing the `time` module.

```py
# ...

while True:
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
```

Here, you're overriding the variable named `time` from above (this is called [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)). The variable `time` now contains a string, so its type is now `str`.

```py
    print(time)
    if time == "06:16":
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(2)  # <===== This gives me error
```

Here, you're trying to call `sleep` on the `time` variable above, which is still a `str`. Since values of type `str` don't have a function `sleep` that you can call on them, you get the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sleep'".

Since you imported `sleep` above with `from time import sleep`, you have the function `sleep` in scope, so you could use `sleep(2)` here instead of `time.sleep(2)`.

Another way to resolve your issue is to prevent the `time` variable from being shadowed, by using a different name. If you called your variable `now` for example, instead of `time`, then `time` would still be bound to the `time` module, and you'd still be able to call `sleep` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry for my noob question!
I finally figure it out the problem.

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import time
from time import sleep

#SETUP THE GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)

#BLINK TEST
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW) #Turns On
time.sleep(3)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH) #Turns off

#TIME PRINT FOR TEST
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))

#TRACK TIME AND TURN ON THE GPIO
while True :
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    print(time)
    if time == "11:41" :
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(1)
        print("YEah baby")

    GPIO.cleanup()
```